# Netbeans Web Service from WSDL "unable to find valid certification"

Tags: java, wsdl, certificate, jax-ws

I try to create in Netbeans a Web Service from WSDL. If I go with a rightclick on the project -> New -> Other -> Web Services -> Web Service from WSDL -> Next
and enter the link to the WSDL file then an error appears:

> Web Service can not be created by JAXWS:wsimport utility. Reason:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIXpath building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExcepton: unable to
>   find valid certification path to reqeusted target

I cannot post the link, because it is private. Nevertheless there has to be a way to import the .p12 certificate, but I don't know how.

It's not a solution to download the WSDL file, because the server has to be flexible with other WSDL files. I program with NetBeans 7.3.1 with linux and Glassfish 4.0.

Comment: Is the WSDL URL https with a self-signed certificate?

Comment: No, it isn't. The problem is like i said in the comment for davidfmatheson, that I have to find a way to import the private key (the .p12 file).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like NetBeans is trying to hit an HTTPS URL that it doesn't have a cert for.  Perhaps it is self-signed on that server?  Generally the process is:

1. Get the certificate file.  In Chrome:

   - Click on the lock icon by the URL
   - Click the "Connection" tab
   - Click the "Certificate information" link
   - Click the "Details" tab
   - Click the "Copy to File..." button
   - Click the "Next" button
   - Select "DER encoded binary..." and save
2. Import that cert into the `cacerts` file of the JDK that NetBeans is using.  The command-line would look something like `<NETBEANS_JDK_HOME>\bin\keytool.exe -import -alias whatever -keystore <NETBEANS_JDK_HOME>\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file C:\path\of\exportedCert.cer`

If you already have `.p12` file instead, and you need to import it, here are some instructions:

http://www.webfarmr.eu/2010/04/import-pkcs12-private-keys-into-jks-keystores-using-java-keytool/

Comment: It's not a self-signed certificate. The problem is that I have to find a way to import the private key. For this I have a .p12 file, but I don't know how to import.